# Factory Girl: can one reopen factory definitions and complete them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, factory-bot

Hi have this special use case, in which I have to define a factory in one file without a certain parameter, and then insert it in the factory definition later. This is a case where I am importing factory definitions from an external dependency (gem, plugin, whtv) and I need to extend it in my project. Something like:

```
# external def
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "somebody@somebodysworld.com"
  end
end


# proj def
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    password "qwerty"
  end
end
```

this code doesn't work, cuz factory girl thinks I'm redefining the factory. But what I'd really want would be extending it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ups... seems I found the answer. Next time, have to check the documentation a bit furtherer...
Here's the answer for anyone interested:

```
# external def
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do
   email "somebody@somebodysworld.com"
 end
end


# proj def
FactoryGirl.modify do
  factory :user do
    password "qwerty"
  end
end
```